# match keys in a dictionary with the string. Instead of looping the keys in a dictionary or string's words

Tags: python

I wish to map the present keys in a dictionary and characters in a string.

Example:

```
dictionary = {"test":"1", "card":"2"} # my concern is that sometimes my dictionary will have thousands of keys so I do not wish to loop each of it.

string = "There istest at the cardboards" # the string will also have a long strings.


for d in dictionary:
    if d in string:
        string = string.replace(d,dictionary[d])
```

If I were to perform this way then it will be very expensive if I have a long input for both dictionary and string.

My current result:

```
"There is1 at the 2board"
```

Expected Result:

(same but without looping either dictionary or string. I wanted to learn some more high-level way of doing it. Thank you.)

```
There is1 at the 2board
```

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Have you timed that with actually large dictionary and string, or just with the toy example from the question?

Comment: That example code replaces each dictionary entry only once, although it might appear multiple times in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

dictionary = {"test":"1", "card":"2"}
str_val = "There istest at the cardboards" 

pattern = re.compile("|".join(dictionary))                      #Create Regex pattern with keys. 
result = pattern.sub(lambda x: dictionary[x.group()], str_val)  #re.sub to replace
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
There is1 at the 2boards
```

Comment: This is slower that what the OP currently has, `641 ns ± 6.01 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each` is the time for the OP's logic, and `2.9 µs ± 54.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)` for your logic so 5 times slower

Comment: Is there a faster version of this because this is somehow slower? and also can I know what is the x.group() for?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, it is faster than for loops.

```py
import time

dictionary = {'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4', 'five': '5'}

string = 'The number is one two two 9 five three 10 four'
string = string.split()

#################solution 1#####################
string1 = string.copy()
st = time.clock()

# solution one, using for loop
for i, s in enumerate(string1):
    if s in dictionary.keys():
        string1[i] = dictionary[s]

t = time.clock() - st
print('time cost: {}'.format(t))
print(' '.join(string1))

################solution 2#####################
string2 = string.copy()
st = time.clock()

# solution 2
string2 = [s if s not in dictionary.keys() else dictionary[s] for s in string2]

t = time.clock() - st
print('time cost: {}'.format(t))
print(' '.join(string2))


time cost: 5.999999999999062e-06
The number is 1 2 2 9 5 3 10 4
time cost: 2.999999999999531e-06
The number is 1 2 2 9 5 3 10 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this solution:

```
dictionary = {"test":"1", "card":"2"}
keys = list(dictionary)
print(keys)
['test', 'card']
string = "There istest at the cardboards"
temp_string = string
for i in keys:
    if i in temp_string:
        temp_string = temp_string.replace(i,str(keys.index(i)+1))

print(temp_string)
'There is1 at the 2boards'
```

Answer (score 0):

By using reduce

```
dictionary = {"test":"1", "card":"2"}
string = "There istest at the cardboards"

from functools import reduce
res = reduce(lambda k, v: k.replace(v, dictionary[v]), dictionary, string)

## 'There is1 at the 2boards'
```

Comment: This method is fast but why do we use k.replace and not v.replace? I thought k represents dictionary and v represents string? Then we should replace the string and not the dictionary, rogjt?

Comment: Can you explain a litle about this method please. I wish to understand

Answer (score 0):

Combine all your keys in the dictionary into one huge regular expression:
`(test|card|...)`

Make sure to *compile* that regular expression (regex) once. That's the most expensive operation.

Subsequently, use the compiled regex to search for matches in your input string. The braces `(` and `)` define a group. That means when you found a match, you can retrieve the contents of the group, so you'll know whether you found 'test', 'card', or one of the other candidates. Then use that value to look up the replacement.

I wouldn't recommend to change the string while you're looping over it. Instead, build a second string, where you copy unchanged sections of the original string and replacements from the dictionary lookup as required.

---

*without looping either dictionary or string*

There's no way to do what you want without looping both. You might find some declarative way to *describe* what you want, but somewhere down the line, the processor must *execute* loops through both dictionary and string to compute what you want.
The best you can hope to achieve is that the processor loops each only once (n + m iterations), instead of running a nested loop (n * m iterations).

Comment: So there's the declarative way to hide the underlying loops: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56521101/11451509